# Проблема с созданием образа Api в Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

[image: Это мой DockerFile]

Это мой Dockerfile. При docker build -t games.web  выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте добавить src/Games.Web/Games.web.csproj

Comment: Пожалуйста вставляйте текстовую информацию текстом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 1):

Пути в `Dockerfile` указываются относительно контекста (папки) указанного в команде `docker build` ([docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description), [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)).

`docker build -t games.web <path>` (кстати, вы в вопросе указали вообще без пути, так оно не должно работать вообще), означает что оно будет искать файл `Games.Web/Games.Web.csproj` по пути `<path>`.

Например, если вы выполняете эту команду из папки с sln-файлом, то она должна выглядеть так (точка означает текущую папку):

```
docker build -t games.web -f Games.Web/Dockerfile .
```

А если из `Games.Web` папки с проектом и `Dockerfile`, то

```
docker build -t games.web -f ./Dockerfile ..
```

Т.е. мы говорим, что в качестве контекста мы используем не только папку с проектом, а весь solution.